Argument path error when trying to get file from URL and pass to openai API
I'm attempting to get a PDF file from a publicly available URL and pass it to openai via their API, but consistently getting a type error. Here's the code I'm using, fetching the file and then converting it to a stream to pass to the api:
const fileURL = "https://public-url.pdf";

const response = await fetch(fileURL);
if (!response.ok) {
    throw `HTTP Response Code: ${response.status}`;
}

const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer(); 
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
const readableStream = await Readable.from(uint8Array);

const selection = await openai.files.create({
    //file: fs.createReadStream(fileFull),
    file: fs.createReadStream(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)),
    purpose: "assistants"
});

I'm getting the following error:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received Uint8Array(1235611) [
   37,  80,  68,  70,  45,  49,  46,  55,  10,  49,  32,  48,
   32, 111,  98, 106,  60,  60,  47,  80,  9...
    at new ReadStream (node:internal/fs/streams:185:5)
    at Object.createReadStream (node:fs:3109:10)

I can remove null bytes but they're an important part of the PDF stream. How do I get this file from a URL and pass to openai?
Thanks!
